# Why is selenium getAttribute("href") not working?

Tags: java, selenium

**Summary:** My code goes to a craigslist ad url. It extracts the hidden phone numbers in the ad body. The code works fine for many urls except the one which I have included in the code. (Btw, you can copy and run my code without writing any additional code.)

**Problem:** The `getAttribute("href")` is returning a `null` only for this url. Why ? How do I fix this ?

**Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Temp {
    private static final WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
    private static WebDriver temp_browser = new ChromeDriver();

    /*The code fails only for this url.*/
    private static String url = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/pen/apa/5764613878.html";

    public static String phone_btns_xpath = "//section[@id='postingbody']//*[contains(.,'show contact info')]";
    public static By phone_btns_loc = By.xpath(phone_btns_xpath);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        browser.get(url);
        List<String> phones = reveal_hidden_phone_numbers(temp_browser);
        temp_browser.close();
        System.out.println(phones);
    }

    public static List<String> reveal_hidden_phone_numbers(WebDriver temp_browser) {
        List<WebElement> phone_btns = browser.findElements(phone_btns_loc);
        List<String> phones = null;
        String text = null;

        if (phone_btns.size() > 0) {
            WebElement phone_btn_0 = phone_btns.get(0);
            System.out.println(phone_btn_0.getAttribute("innerHTML"));

            String url = phone_btn_0.getAttribute("href");
            temp_browser.get(url);
            text = temp_browser.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();

            for (WebElement phone_btn : phone_btns) {
                phone_btn.click();
            }

            phones = extract_phone_numbers(text);
        }
        return phones;
    }

    public static List<String> extract_phone_numbers(String text) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        output.add("PHONE ;)");
        return output;
    }

}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
 <a href="/fb/sfo/apa/5764613878" class="showcontact" title="click to show contact info" rel="nofollow">show contact info</a>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null
    at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)
    at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.<init>(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:39)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap.of(ImmutableBiMap.java:49)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(ImmutableMap.java:70)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
    at com.craigslist.Temp.reveal_hidden_phone_numbers(Temp.java:38)
    at com.craigslist.Temp.main(Temp.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: What did System.out.println(phone_btn_0.getAttribute("innerHTML")); output?  Try the following to see which attributes are available.  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes", phone_btn_0));
element);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm seeing in your provided stacktrace this line `System.out.println(phone_btn_0.getAttribute("innerHTML"));` from your code printed the inner HTML of `phone_btn_0` element as :-

> `<a href="/fb/sfo/apa/5764613878" class="showcontact" title="click to show contact info" rel="nofollow">show contact info</a>`

That means you're trying to get `href` attribute on wrong element. It's on parent element instead of actual link element where `href` attribute does not exist, that's why you're getting `null`.

Assuming you want to get `href` attribute value from this printed link element `HTML`, So you should try to get `href` attribute value on the child element of `phone_btn_0` as below :-

```
WebElement phone_btn_0 = phone_btns.get(0);
System.out.println(phone_btn_0.getAttribute("innerHTML"));

String url = phone_btn_0.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href");
```

**Edited** :- You can also fix it initially in `xpath` to locate only `a` element instead of  all `*` with your same code as well as :-

```
public static String phone_btns_xpath = "//section[@id='postingbody']//a[contains(.,'show contact info')]";
```

Comment: Or I could fix my xpath to look for 'a' instead of * or all elements. I thought I got that right.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you can also fix it initially in xpath to locate only a instead of `*` as `public static String phone_btns_xpath = "//section[@id='postingbody']//a[contains(.,'show contact info')]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .to string method like below ..its working for me
String url = phone_btn_0.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href").toString();